# Почему получаю OutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, массивы, scanner

При запуске, программы, получаю OutOfBoundsException в `points[0] = pointFiller(scanner);` Не могу понять почему...

Заранее **благодарю за ответы**

---

```
public class Point {
    private int lineCount;
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    Point[] points = new Point[lineCount];

    public void pointsCreator() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        lineCount = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println("enter points for first line: ");
        points[0] = pointFiller(scanner);

        for (int i = 1; i < lineCount; i++){
            System.out.println("----------------------");
            System.out.println("enter points for next line:");
            points[i] = pointFiller(scanner);
        }

        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(points));
    }

    public static Point pointFiller(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.print("     - enter x: ");
        int x = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("     - enter y: ");
        int y = scanner.nextInt();

        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Points for line {x = " + x + ", y = " + y + '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это происходит потому что по умолчанию `lineCount` инициализируется нулем, далее Вы создаете массив нулевой длины:

```
Point[] points = new Point[lineCount];
```

А уже после создания массива Вы вводите значение `lineCount`.

Попробуйте вот так:

```
public class Point {
    private int lineCount;
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    Point[] points;

    public void pointsCreator() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        lineCount = scanner.nextInt();

        points = new Point[lineCount];

        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println("enter points for first line: ");
        points[0] = pointFiller(scanner);

        for (int i = 1; i < lineCount; i++){
            System.out.println("----------------------");
            System.out.println("enter points for next line:");
            points[i] = pointFiller(scanner);
        }

        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(points));
    }

    public static Point pointFiller(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.print("     - enter x: ");
        int x = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("     - enter y: ");
        int y = scanner.nextInt();

        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Points for line {x = " + x + ", y = " + y + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: `points =  = new Point[lineCount];` Здесь что-то пропущено?

Comment: Все, разобрался!

Comment: @AlexonClassic, Там опечатка была.

Comment: @AlexonClassic, не используйте ответы для благодарностей. Просто пометьте ответ, как принятый (зеленая галочка под голосовалкой).

Answer (score 2):

```
Point[] points = new Point[lineCount];
```

В момент, когда выполняется эта строка, `lineCount == 0`. После чего вы логично получаете выход за пределы массива, т.к. массив имеет нулевую длину.

Инициализируйте массив после того как получите значение `lineCount` с консоли.

Comment: Т. е. в методе pointsCreator

Comment: то есть да, в нем.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы массив, был отдельно (ну т. е. за методом pointsCreator)

Comment: @AlexonClassic, Так объявите его отдельно, а создавайте в методе.

Comment: Сорри, туплю... Что-то не могу понять как...

P. S. Я только изучаю Java

Comment: `Point[] points;` - объявил